# a question about how to calculate a determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determinant of a specially structured matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86644/determinant-of-a-specially-structured-matrix)
>   [Determining eigenvalues, eigenvectors of $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}(n\geq 2)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168118/determining-eigenvalues-eigenvectors-of-a-in-mathbbrn-times-nn-geq-2)

I have the following matrix
$$
 A =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  n-1 & -1 & \cdots & -1 \\
  -1 & n-1 & \cdots & -1 \\
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
  -1 & -1 & \cdots & n-1
 \end{pmatrix}
$$
and I need to calculate $det(A)$. How could I calculate this determinant and which are the eigenvalues ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**HINT:**

$$
 A =
 nI - 
 \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
  1 & 1 & \cdots & 1
 \end{pmatrix} = nI - \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\ \vdots\\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
Can you compute the eigen-values of the matrix $I - \alpha u v^T$, where $u,v$ are vectors?

Answer (score 3):

I'll assume that $A$ is $k\times k$. Let us form the matrix of all ones, call it $J$. Then we can represent $A$ as
$$A=nI - J$$
To calculate the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is equivalent to finding
$$\det\left((n-\lambda)I - J\right)$$
Notice that $J$ is diagonalizable since it is symmetric. $J$ has rank $1$ and it is quite easy to see that $k$ is an eigenvalue under the eigenvector of all $1$s. So the eigenvalues of $J$ are all $0$ except for $k$ which has multiplicity $1$. Therefore the characteristic polynomial of the above matrix will be $$(n-\lambda)^{k-1}(n-\lambda-k)$$