# Evaluate $\underbrace{\idotsint}_n \exp\left(-\sum_{1\le i\le j\le n}^n x_i x_j\right) \mathrm{d}x_1\cdots\mathrm{d}x_n $

Tags: integration

I am currently studying V.I. Arnold's course, and I am stuck on this exercise:

Evaluate 
$$
\underbrace{\idotsint}_{n} 
\exp\left(-\sum_{1\le i\le j\le n}^n x_i x_j\right)
\mathrm{d}x_1\cdots\mathrm{d}x_n 
$$

Can anyone suggest a hint? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried the small cases $n=1,2,3$; then tried to generalize?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Having read a lot of things by Arnold, I think his point of view was that "every student should know" the formula
$$\int\ldots\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\exp\left\{-\frac12 x^TAx\right\}dx_1\ldots dx_n=\frac{(2\pi)^{n/2}}{\sqrt{\mathrm{det}\,A}},\tag{1}$$
where $x^T=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ and $A$ is a real symmetric positive definite $n\times n$ matrix. Actually, every physics student should know it indeed.

What remains is a [simple linear algebra exercise](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/168118/73025).

---

**Added**: The gaussian integration formula (1) is obtained by noticing that the matrix $A$ can be brought to diagonal form by orthogonal transformation, characterized by unit jacobian. Then one is left with a product of gaussian integrals $\prod_{k=1}^n\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\{-\lambda_k x^2/2\}dx$, where $\lambda_{1\ldots n}$ denote the eigenvalues of $A$.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: Diagonalize the symmetric matrix
$$
A=-\frac12\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
2&1&1&\cdots&1\\
1&2&1&\cdots&1\\
1&1&2&\cdots&1\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
1&1&1&\cdots&2
\end{array}\right)?
$$
Diagonalization of a quadratic form in the exponential = separation of variables.

Comment: I changed what looked like a typo. Let me know.

Comment: Then the answer should be like $\displaystyle |A^{\frac{1}{2}}|\left(\int \exp(-x^2)dx\right)^n$ right?

Comment: I worked it out. The diagonal matrix is $\left[
\begin{matrix}
1& & & & \\
 &1& & & \\
 & &\ddots& & \\
 & & &1& \\
 & & & & n+1
\end{matrix}\right]$. So by n-dimensional Gaussian integral the final result is $\frac{(2 \pi )^{n/2}}{\sqrt{n+1}}? $

Comment: @YorkTsang: That's what I got, too (don't forget that $-1/2$). Note that as $A$ is symmetric, it can be diagonalized with an orthogonal matrix, so the Jacobian of this linear change of variables is $=1$ (orthogonality not essential here, but sometimes else it is).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Thank you for your hint!

Comment: OOPS. Orthogonality IS essential. Diagonalization naturally uses the inverse of a matrix, but the quadratic form uses the transpose. Transpose = inverse, when the matrix is orthogonal. Sorry about that.