# Smart method for computing the determinant of the matrix defined by $A_{ii}=a+b$ and $A_{ij}=a$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

We are given the following $n\times n$ matrix, whose terms are:

- $a+b$ for the terms in the diagonal ($i=j$).
- $a$ for the rest of the elements.

I know we can simply compute this and try to find a pattern, but is there a faster way? Maybe using some properties of the determinant of a matrix?

Comment: Hint. Do you know what happens to the determinant when you subtract one row from another?

Comment: It does not change, does it?

Comment: Correct. That and expansion by minors on a column that's mostly $0$ should help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determining eigenvalues, eigenvectors of $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}(n\geq 2)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168118/determining-eigenvalues-eigenvectors-of-a-in-mathbbrn-times-nn-geq-2)

Comment: I still do not know what eigenvalues are, neither eigenvectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align*}
& \begin{vmatrix}
a + b & a     & a     & \cdots & a \\
a     & a + b & a     & \cdots & a \\
a     & a     & a + b & \cdots & a\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a     & a     & a     & \cdots &a + b 
\end{vmatrix} \\
= & \begin{vmatrix}
na + b & na + b   & na + b     & \cdots & na + b \\
a     & a + b & a     & \cdots & a \\
a     & a     & a + b & \cdots & a\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a     & a     & a     & \cdots &a + b 
\end{vmatrix} \\
= & (na + b)\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1   & 1     & \cdots & 1 \\
a     & a + b & a     & \cdots & a \\
a     & a     & a + b & \cdots & a\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a     & a     & a     & \cdots &a + b 
\end{vmatrix} \\
= & (na + b)\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1   & 1     & \cdots & 1 \\
0     & b & 0    & \cdots & 0 \\
0     & 0    & b & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0     & 0    & 0   & \cdots & b 
\end{vmatrix} \\
=& (na + b)b^{n - 1}
\end{align*}

Can you figure out what operations I used in each step?

Comment: Thank you! It's almost what I did! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Let  $\mathbf e_i$ denote the $i$th standard base vector and $\mathbf j=\sum\mathbf e_i$ denote the "all-ones" vector.

Clearly, $A\mathbf j=(b+na)\mathbf j$, so $\mathbf j$ is an eigenvector of eigenvalue $b+na$.

Also $A\mathbf e_i=b\mathbf e_i+a\mathbf j$ so that for $2\le i\le n$, $A(\mathbf e_i-\mathbf e_1)=b(\mathbf e_i-\mathbf e_1)$, i.e., we know $n-1$ linearly independent eigenvectors of eigenvalue $b$.

All in all, we have found a basis consisting of eigenvectors an know their eigenvalues, and can
conclude that $$\det A=(b+na)\cdot b^{n-1}.$$

Comment: Thank you! Awesome, although I still do not know what eigen-stuff is.

Answer (score 0):

The given matrix may be written as $bI_n+\mathbf a\mathbf1^T$ where $\mathbf x$ denotes a vector consisting of $n$ copies of $\mathbf x$. The [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma) gives the required determinant as
$$(1+\mathbf 1^T(I_n/b)\mathbf a)\det bI_n=(1+na/b)b^n=b^n+nab^{n-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma).

You have

$$C = b I + a {\bf u}  {\bf u}^t$$

where ${ \bf u}$ a all-ones column vector.

Then $$\det(C) = (1 + a {\bf u}^t({b}I)^{-1}  {\bf u}) \det(b I) $$

Can you go on from here?

Comment: The problem is supposed to be solved by only using determinant properties... not that advanced lemma, although it makes things a lot easier.